# Turn off the camera shutter sound on iPhone SE running iOS 12.1.4

Tags: ios, camera

I need to take a picture silently. Currently the only way I've found to silence the shutter sound is to enable Live Photo.

My iPhone 5s on iOS 10.x obeys the ringer/silent switch setting, but the following methods reported around the Web do not appear to work for my iPhone SE running iOS 12.1.4:

- Enable silent mode
- Turn down the sound effects volume in the control center
- Turn down the ringer volume
- Turn off screen lock sounds

No combination of the above produces the desired effect; the shutter always sounds unless Live Photo is enabled.

Am I missing something? As far as I know this phone has a European firmware.

Comment: Can you [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/355221/edit) the question and specify the [model code](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Model_Regions) for your device?

Comment: Hmm my XS Max seems to obey the ringer silent switch even if Live Photos are off. (& Ringer sound is not turned down)

Comment: @dwightk - hmmm... just checked, my 6S does too. Silent means silent.

Answer (score 1):

You found one of the methods, Live Photo.

The other is simply to turn the ringer sound down to zero.

Source - [Lifewire - How to Turn off the Camera Sound on iPhone](https://www.lifewire.com/turn-off-iphone-camera-sound-4174957)

I think the limitation on the ringer mute no longer working is because of recent legislation. No longer is 'upskirting' merely deeply offensive, it is now actually illegal.
That there is still a workaround is possibly an oversight & may be fixed in future.